# Why Postgres is ignoring all my indexes on conditional join?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

I have two tables: `campaign` and `stats`. `stats` table contains daily stats I am trying to aggregate for every campaign, nothing extraordinary.

I indexed all the fields I can think of, yet none of the indexes are used from what I can tell. I know Postgres might choose not to use an index, but it still looks suspicious, and the query isn't lightning fast either. How can I help it?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "campaign"."id", "campaign"."name", "campaign"."status", SUM("stats"."impressions") AS "impressions" 
    FROM "campaign" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "stats" ON 
        ("stats"."date" >= '2016-03-27'::date) 
        AND ("stats"."date" <= '2016-04-25'::date) 
        AND ("campaign"."id" = "stats"."campaign_id") 
    GROUP BY "campaign"."id" 
    ORDER BY "campaign"."status" ASC, "campaign"."created" DESC 
    LIMIT 25;
```

Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=6445.26..6445.32 rows=25 width=53) (actual time=642.134..642.422 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=6445.26..6446.80 rows=617 width=53) (actual time=642.113..642.209 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: campaign.status, campaign.created
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=6421.68..6427.85 rows=617 width=53) (actual time=634.619..637.342 rows=617 loops=1)
               Group Key: campaign.id
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=58.88..6269.08 rows=30519 width=53) (actual time=9.986..481.628 rows=31142 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (stats.campaign_id = campaign.id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on stats  (cost=0.00..5790.56 rows=30519 width=8) (actual time=0.044..172.346 rows=31027 loops=1)
                           Filter: ((date >= '2016-03-27'::date) AND (date <= '2016-04-25'::date))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 22299
                     ->  Hash  (cost=51.17..51.17 rows=617 width=49) (actual time=9.325..9.325 rows=617 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 52kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on campaign  (cost=0.00..51.17 rows=617 width=49) (actual time=0.043..4.490 rows=617 loops=1)
 Planning time: 1.778 ms
 Execution time: 643.217 ms
```

Tables:

```
                                         Table "public.campaign"
        Column        |           Type           |                           Modifiers                           
----------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer                  | not null default nextval('campaign_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                 | character varying(255)   | not null
 created              | timestamp with time zone | not null
 status               | character varying(32)    | not null
Indexes:
    "campaign_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "campaign_9acb4454" btree (status)
    "campaign_9bea82de" btree (product_id)
    "campaign_created_7aea656cce4d74c_uniq" btree (created)
Foreign-key constraints:
    TABLE "stats" CONSTRAINT "stats_campaign_id_dabb6227_fk_campaign_id" FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES campaign(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED


                                      Table "public.stats"
     Column      |          Type           |                         Modifiers                          
-----------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                 | not null default nextval('stats_id_seq'::regclass)
 date            | date                    | not null
 impressions     | integer                 | not null
 campaign_id     | integer                 | not null
Indexes:
    "stats_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "stats_date_1de4ab17_uniq" btree (date)
    "stats_f14acec3" btree (campaign_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "stats_campaign_id_dabb6227_fk_campaign_id" FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES campaign(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

===============

Edit:

Query plan if the condition is moved out of JOIN into WHERE:

```
Limit  (cost=10252.48..10252.55 rows=25 width=252) (actual time=921.152..921.423 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=10252.48..10254.03 rows=617 width=252) (actual time=921.142..921.230 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: campaign.status, campaign.created
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 37kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=10161.03..10235.07 rows=617 width=252) (actual time=910.690..916.553 rows=550 loops=1)
               Group Key: campaign.id
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=58.88..6575.05 rows=30519 width=252) (actual time=7.655..708.881 rows=31075 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (stats.campaign_id = campaign.id)
                     Filter: ((stats.date IS NULL) OR ((stats.date >= '2016-03-27'::date) AND (stats.date <= '2016-04-25'::date)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 22299
                     ->  Seq Scan on stats  (cost=0.00..5526.71 rows=52771 width=56) (actual time=0.009..249.230 rows=53326 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=51.17..51.17 rows=617 width=204) (actual time=7.588..7.588 rows=617 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 128kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on campaign  (cost=0.00..51.17 rows=617 width=204) (actual time=0.009..3.124 rows=617 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.604 ms
 Execution time: 922.323 ms
```

Comment: Well I think PostgreSQL should be able to use an index on the date field. What's the proportion of `stats` selected with `("stats"."date" >= '2016-03-27'::date) AND ("stats"."date" <= '2016-04-25'::date)` ? Did you vacuum recently ?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost It's around 50% of records. If I change the date range to 1 day it does use the index on date. Alright lets assume the date index is fine, why nothing else though, why does it do the seq scan on campaign (last row in the plan) which seems like the most obvious one to index? Also I don't vacuum it manually, I thought it should be automatic.

Comment: It is automatic, that was just to make sure. Does that change anything if you put the `("stats"."date" >= '2016-03-27'::date) AND ("stats"."date" <= '2016-04-25'::date)` out of the join clause ? Something like `WHERE (stats.date is null OR (("stats"."date" >= '2016-03-27'::date) AND ("stats"."date" <= '2016-04-25'::date))`. I guess that the join condition is too complex to let PostgreSQL understand that the date filter is in fact a filter and not a join condition

Comment: @ClémentPrévost I added the plan output for that case, it doesn't use any of the indexes still and runs even slower (which is expected I guess, since now it has to filter whole stats table)

Comment: Well I think you shouldn't look for a misused index here, the biggest improvement might be to limit campaigns early and then add stats to that. Do you have to sort on stat data ? If you don't I could rewrite the query to force the limit to be executed before the join.

Comment: @ClémentPrévost yeah I need to be able to sort by stat fields too. Feel free to post your solution I'm sure someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider writing the query like this:

```
SELECT c."id", c."name", c."status",
       (SELECT SUM(s."impressions")
        FROM "stats" s
        WHERE c."id" = s."campaign_id" AND
              s."date" >= '2016-03-27'::date AND
              s."date" <= '2016-04-25'::date
       ) as "impressions" 
FROM "campaign" c
ORDER BY c."status" ASC, c."created" DESC ;
```

Then the best indexes are `campaign(status, created desc, name, id)` and `stats(campaign_id, date, impressions)`.  Note:  these are both multi-column indexes which fully cover the query (meaning all accessed columns are in the indexes).

The Postgres optimizer is good.  However,  don't think it is good enough to optimize away the outer aggregation in your form of the query.  Because it can use the index for the `ORDER BY`, this version using a correlated subquery may be faster than versions using explicit `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I have lots of calculated stats columns besides impressions, can I use this method still?

Comment: @serg . . . Start with this query and see if it improves performance.  If so, then try a lateral join.  If that still performs well (and it should), then add the additional columns.

Comment: How do I add additional columns though, add one subquery per every calculated field? Or I am missing the obvious. Can you please post a query for 2 fields. Or you mean to do it in two queries - first select all the campaigns, then select stats for those campaign ids. This would be inconvenient if I wanted to order by some stat field (like sum of impressions).

Comment: @seng . . . You can do this using a lateral join.  You just want to check to be sure that Postgres optimizes the query correctly.

Comment: @JohnMudd . . . A lateral join would be pretty much the same thing, except moving the correlated subquery to the `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you limit first, you might be able to speed things up, but you can't do that if you want to sort on `stats` aggregations

```
WITH top_campaign (
    SELECT *
    FROM "campaign" 
    ORDER BY "campaign"."status" ASC, "campaign"."created" DESC 
    LIMIT 25
)
SELECT "campaign"."id", "campaign"."name", "campaign"."status", SUM("stats"."impressions") AS "impressions" 
FROM "top_campaign" as "campaign" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "stats" ON ("campaign"."id" = "stats"."campaign_id") AND ("stats"."date" >= '2016-03-27'::date) AND ("stats"."date" <= '2016-04-25'::date) 
GROUP BY "campaign"."id" 
ORDER BY "campaign"."status" ASC, "campaign"."created" DESC
```